# How to position layout off the screen

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to reach the following result:
My `RelativeLayout` overlay initially should look like that [image: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4277073/view1.png] . So only 20% of the layout should be seen.

when `Button` is pressed i apply `Animation` so that layout goes up and looks the following [image: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4277073/view2.png]

Overlay layout is placed in the parent `RelativeLayout` and has number of `ImageButtons` in it.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/overlay"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/actionbar"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/backgroundfeedme"
    android:clickable="true"
     >
 -----number of img buttons here -- 
 </RelativeLayout>
```

I was trying to set up its initial position as follows

```
rlOverlay = (RelativeLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.overlay);
ViewTreeObserver vto = rlOverlay.getViewTreeObserver();
vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
@Override
      public void onGlobalLayout() {
           WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) MainActivity.appContext.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
           Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
           int height = display.getHeight();  // deprecated, my app is for API 2.1+
           rlOverlay.layout(0, (int)(height*0.8), rlOverlay.getMeasuredWidth(), rlOverlay.getMeasuredHeight());
      }
    });
```

Unfortunately the code above doesnt affect position of the layout.
I also cant use marginTop, because it squeezes the layout.

So .. how to position my layout so that only 20% of it is visible initially?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered using animations? Position the `RelativeLayout` in it's final position and on creation animate it down. When the button is pressed, animate it up.

Comment: @NeilTownsend actually i didnt think of that!! sounds good, should make the trick.
I am trying to make it work now..it just takes time, i am very new to animations. THANKS

Answer (score 0):

i had same requirment. what i did is put two relative layout. in first layout took button and below it second layout with rest of my views and Visiblity = gone.

from code: when i click on Button i made seond layout visiblity = Visible and animate it.

here's code:

```
    <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/llShopping"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/bar_green" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnShoppingListAddItem"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/bar_green"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:text="Add Item"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relAddItemChild"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnShoppingListAddItem"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <View
            android:id="@+id/gl"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edtItemName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/gl"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:hint="Item Name..." />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSpinner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/edtItemName"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="Please pick store" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnAddToList"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btnSpinner"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_blue"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Add To List"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer.
I like your suggestion. However I dont think i can have fixed image shape for my button. I am using a background image for blue overlay. However depending on screen resolution it stretches differently so it might have different angle. Thats why i guess i can't crop my image for my button.
Or is there any other approach?